# Construct pair of unique_ptr<int> and int

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, stl, std-pair

I'm trying to create a pair of int and a unique_ptr. How should I use make_pair to create this ?

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> p = std::make_unique<int>(0);
    std::pair<int, std::unique_ptr<int>> pr = std::make_pair((int)0, p);
}
```

I run into the following issue,

```
Error   C2440   '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to '_Mypair'    templpairuniqueptr  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\utility 405
```

I could not understand why this happens. I'm on MSVC.

Comment: Your issue is not specific to priority_queue at all, so any mentioning of it is just noise. Please isolate the code in question in MCVE and ask pointed question.

Comment: I removed a lot of code to isolate this part. Let me remove some more. May be that should help me resolve the issue. I'm sure it happens when trying to construct the pair.

Comment: You need to `std::move(p)` when creating the pair, or pass the return value on directly.

Comment: @SergeyA If you remember, I was moving my unique_ptr in and out of the queue! The compiler error did not help (me at least) understand the problem. I still run into the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot copy unique pointers. After all, the copy would not be unique. Move instead:

```
auto pr = std::make_pair(
    0, std::make_unique<int>(0)
);
```

You can move from lvalues as well, if you need to, by converting the lvalue to an rvalue with `std::move`:

```
auto pr = std::make_pair(
    0, std::move(p)
);
```